# UserProfileManager is inaccessible due to its protection level in sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to build a solution for SharePoint2010 Foundation on a different Development Environment in Visual Studio 2010 RTM.

This solution is deployed on SharePoint Foundation 2010 and it is working fine but when we are trying to build the code in our environment we are getting the below error:

Error

> " Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager  is
>   inaccessible due to its protection level"

below are the code where exactly I am getting error.

```
    public UserInfo Userprofile(string UserAccountName)
    {
        string UserName = string.Empty;
        UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo();
        try
        {

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(GetContextURL()))
            {
                SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
                ProfileBase[] Users = profileManager.Search(UserAccountName);

                foreach (UserProfile user in Users)
                {
                    if (user["AccountName"] != null && user["AccountName"].ToString().ToLower() == UserAccountName.ToLower())
                    {
                        userinfo = LoadProfileData(user);

                    }
                }


                return userinfo;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return userinfo;

    }
```

We are referencing ddl name(`Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll`) which is being used for User Profile management.

Due to the error I am unable to build the solution. Any help in this would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance